# Problems passing a BSTR from native c++ to managed c# dll

Tags: c#, c++, com, native, managed

forgive me if this has been answered before but I have not found a solution that works for me. I've seen many answers for passing a string from C# to C++ but not so many the other way around.
Issue is I have a c++ application that needs to load a C# dll and pass it a string.

on the C# side of things I have this exposed through com.

```
namespace DriverCollect
{

    public interface IDriverInfo
    {

        int GetDriverInfo(ref string name);

    };


    public class DriverInterface:IDriverInfo
    {

        public int GetDriverInfo(ref string drivername)
        {
            DriverInfo myInfo = new DriverInfo(@"c:\logfile.txt") ;

            myInfo.Collect(drivername);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used regasm to register the tbl file and this is what I see in OLE type lib viewer

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(F3005FE7-DBA1-3FB6-807E-E66626EC875B),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "DriverCollect.IDriverInfo")

]
interface IDriverInfo : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000)]
    HRESULT GetDriverInfo(
                    [in, out] BSTR* name, 
                    [out, retval] long* pRetVal);
};
```

on the C++ side of things this is my test case.

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

IDriverInfoPtr pDriverInfo(__uuidof(DriverInterface));

if(pDriverInfo)
   m_pDriverInfo = pDriverInfo;

BSTR s(L"c:\\xmltestdir\\cdromarm.sys");
long ret = 1;
hr = m_pDriverInfo->GetDriverInfo(&s,&ret);

CoUninitialize()
```

;

What happens is is that the BSTR is always empty when it is received by the C# dll. Other than that I get no errors, the ret value is changed when the function returns and the HRESULT is S_OK.
I have tried passing the BSTR by value also to the same effect.

Thoughts?

Comment: any luck when you remove the ref in  public int GetDriverInfo(ref string drivername)?

Comment: No, my initial try was GetDriverInfo(string name); which has oletype viewer showing GetDriverInfo as GetDriverInfo([in] BSTR) but that also results in an empty string ( not NULL just empty "" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BSTR does not have a length prefix when you declare it so

```
BSTR s(L"c:\\xmltestdir\\cdromarm.sys");
```

Try declaring it so

```
BSTR s = SysAllocString(L"c:\\xmltestdir\\cdromarm.sys");
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),
*If you pass a simple Unicode string as an argument to a COM function that is expecting a BSTR, the COM function will fail.*

Also consider using CComBSTR or _bstr_t instead which manages the memory (allocating and freeing from the OLE heap) for you in case of exceptions.

Comment: Perfect!  This solves the problem !! ( still passing by ref but I suppose I could alter the C# to remove it )

Comment: Interesting to note that ( after removing the refs ) you can use CComBSTR s(L"c:\\xmltestdir\\cdromarm.sys"); and have a correctly allocated BSTR from Constructor initialization whereas BSTR s(L"c:\\xmltestdir\\cdromarm.sys"); fails.  Once again thanks!'

Comment: @Himilou, `BSTR s(L"c:.....");` fails because `BSTR` is not a helper class; it's [simply a typedef for "wchar_t*"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069(v=vs.85).aspx). The compiler cannot tell the difference between `BSTR` and a plain Unicode string pointer because - as far as the compiler is concerned - they are the same exact thing. The `CComBSTR` helper class, on the other hand, knows the difference and calls the correct API in its constructor.